# HTTP request from XQuery code inside MarkLogic pipe

Tags: json, http, pipe, xquery, marklogic

I want to send text using POST method to another HTTP server and receive a JSON file in response from XQuery code of pipe in MarkLogic. The idea is whenever XML or JSON documents are inserted into MarkLogic, it triggers a pipe to read it and sends one element to another web server; in my situation, I want to send to Rosoka server  to do natural language processing, after that I want to store the returned data "it is json file" in MarkLogic.

I appreciate if you could help.

> marklogic only mentioned that is possible but no further help

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this.
A start is to look at "Triggers"

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/triggers

There is also Content Processing Framework ( "CPF" which is a higher level workflow based on triggers).

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cpf

if you read those guides you should be able to ask more specific questions if needed.

Comment: One footnote on Daldei's useful comment -- for sending to the other server, you can use http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:http-post (which blocks until it receives the response).